# How are you the special points/critical points in the Brillouin Zone pronounced?

Tags: soft-question, solid-state-physics, terminology

I know that this isn't exactly physics, but I don't know where to ask.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_zone#Cubic_lattice_system_CUB.281.29.2C_BCC.281.29.2C_FCC.281.29

The critical points/special points are the points that one sees often in bandstructure plots. How are they pronounced? I thought that they were pronounced as the alphabet. E.g. point A is pronounced "Ey", point Z is pronounced is "Zee." But I came across someone who called them alpha and zeta, etc. What is the convention?

Comment: My guess is that the pronounciation is a matter of taste. Since those are the symbols for capital alpha and capital zeta as well, it's quite possible that this is the official convention, but I've never heard them being called that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about pronunciation rather than physics.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard that the non intrinsic greek-written points (mainly $\Gamma$, $\Delta$, $\Lambda$ and $\Sigma$) has been written or spoken as the corresponding greek letters. Might this be a sub-community thing?